# Why does my print not work?

Tags: printing

I have the lastest Ubuntu and updates.   I hardly ever use my printer, but needed to print a letter out.  It says 'processing'.   It has been 'processing' for 30 minutes.   Last time I used it, it just turns on and prints it out.  I have no idea.  I have a Brother HL-L2305W and the printer settings it says it is installed and 'processing'.

Comment: Is there anything interesting in `/var/log/cups/access.log` or `error.log`?

Comment: And if I knew how to look in those files I could tell you.  I'll research how to do that.

Comment: A few hints: open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T), change to that directory (`cd /var/log/cups`), and view those files (`less access_log` and `less error_log`). Also, learn to use `head`, `tail` and `grep` by using the "manual" (`man head`, etc.)

Comment: Apologies: I used incorrect file names in my first comment. These are called `access_log` and `error_log`, respectively.

Comment: I wouldn't know what to look for in the files anyway.  I may try tomorrow.  Thanks

Comment: An actual version of Ubuntu is needed. Latest is time retaliative what about a year from now and is not telling if it is 22.10 or 22.04 both are latest in their stream.

Comment: I hooked it up to my other computer and that one works.

Comment: Is there a command or something that you can type, or somewhere else you can look to get the current version.  I just know that I got that upgrade and have taken all the updates.